# How to get smooth movement in a low resolution game?

Tags: movement, pixel

I am using monogame to make a simple platformer with a fairly low resolution.

Right now I am struggling to get smooth movement like in the mario games. In those games despite having the low resolution mario can still slowly accelerate from standing still and the movement looks smooth. How did they achieve this?

My current solution performs all of the game's physics and movement in floats and when it comes to drawing the x and y coordinate of the player it is rounded to an int. This results in very jagged looking movement.

Is there any way to improve this so that the movement is smooth and still has acceleration? I was thinking about scaling up all of my assets by 4 and working at a higher resolution but then the player would be able to walk between pixels (as 1 pixel in the assets would be represented by 4 pixels on the screen).

Any help would be much appreciate.

Here is an awful video of my character's movement:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=riWk8op2VyY